# Bad jump array solidity and data location

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, bad-jump

I'm having a strange issues with an array inside a struct. I will copy you the example code, so that you can understand:

```
  Foo[] public foos;

  struct Foo {
    uint fooX;
    uint[] fooArray;
  }

  function insertionSort(uint[] a)internal {
   for (uint i = 1;i < a.length;i++){
    uint temp = a[i];
    uint j;
    for (j = i -1; j >= 0 && temp < a[j]; j--)
      a[j+1] = a[j];
    a[j + 1] = temp;
   }
  }

  function doesntWork(uint num,uint _id){
    Foo f = foos[_id];
    f.fooArray[f.fooArray.length++] = nun;
    instertionSort(f.fooArray);
  }

  function work1(uit _id){
    Foo f = foos[_id];
    instertionSort(f.fooArray);
  }

  function work2(uint price,uint pair_id){
    Foo p = pairs[pair_id];
    p.boPrices[p.boPrices.length++] = price;
  }
```

Whenever I am trying to call the insertionSort function on an array, it doesn't work # method 1.

The same function works, when I don't modify the array before hand (as shown in example 2,3).

As my goal is to keep my array sorted after every new value is added it's a problem.

I think it has to do something with the storage of my arrays. But I am having trouble grasping those concept of [Data location](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/types.html#data-location), and how to fix it.

Does a workaround exist there?

Edit: also does the same with [this quickstort](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1517/sorting-an-array-of-integer-with-ethereum)

Comment: If you are interested in keeping an array sorted, it's better to use a structure like [PriorityQueue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) rather that sort array on every update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The Working Solution

```
contract InsertionSort {

    struct Record {
        uint recId;
        uint[] data;
    }

    mapping(uint => Record) records;

    function insertionSortMemory(uint[5] a) internal {
      for (uint i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        uint j = i;
        while (j > 0 && a[j] < a[j-1]) {
          uint temp = a[j];
          a[j] = a[j-1];
          a[j-1] = temp;
          j--;
        }
      }
    }

    function testInsertionSort() public constant returns (uint[5]) {
      uint[5] memory data;
      data[0] = 1235;
      data[1] = 1234;
      data[2] = 1233;
      data[3] = 1232;
      data[4] = 1231;
      insertionSortMemory(data);
      return data;
    }

    function insertionSort(uint[] a, uint length) internal returns (uint[]) {
      for (uint i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        uint j = i;
        while (j > 0 && a[j] < a[j-1]) {
          uint temp = a[j];
          a[j] = a[j-1];
          a[j-1] = temp;
          j--;
        }
      }
      return a;
    }

    function addRecordWithoutInsertionSort(uint _recId, uint _num) public {
        Record record = records[_recId];
        record.recId = _recId;
        record.data.length++;
        record.data[record.data.length-1] = _num;
    }

    function addRecordWithInsertionSort(uint _recId, uint _num) public {
        Record record = records[_recId];
        record.recId = _recId;
        record.data.length++;
        record.data[record.data.length-1] = _num;
        record.data = insertionSort(record.data, record.data.length);
    }



    function getRecord(uint _recId) public constant returns(uint, uint[]) {
        return (records[_recId].recId, records[_recId].data);
    }
}
```

---

## The Test Results

### Testing The Insertion Sort Algorithm

And the algorithm is working correctly.

```
> insertionSort.testInsertionSort()
[1231, 1232, 1233, 1234, 1235]
```

### Testing The Rest Of The Code

Lets insert some records first, without calling the `insertionSort()` function :

```
> insertionSort.addRecordWithoutInsertionSort(123, 1233, eth.accounts[0], {
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: insertionSortCompiled.InsertionSort.code,
    gas: 1000000
});
> insertionSort.addRecordWithoutInsertionSort(123, 1235, eth.accounts[0], {
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: insertionSortCompiled.InsertionSort.code,
    gas: 1000000
});
> insertionSort.addRecordWithoutInsertionSort(123, 1231, eth.accounts[0], {
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: insertionSortCompiled.InsertionSort.code,
    gas: 1000000
});
> insertionSort.addRecordWithoutInsertionSort(123, 1232, eth.accounts[0], {
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: insertionSortCompiled.InsertionSort.code,
    gas: 1000000
});
```

Wait for transactions to be mined, and the records will be unsorted as we have not called the insertion sort yet

```
> insertionSort.getRecord(123);
[123, [1233, 1235, 1231, 1232]]
```

Insert one more record, with the `addRecordWithInsertionSort()` function calling the `insertionSort()` function:

```
> insertionSort.addRecordWithInsertionSort(123, 1234, eth.accounts[0], {
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: insertionSortCompiled.InsertionSort.code,
    gas: 2000000
});
```

Wait for this transaction to be mined, and the sort is working as expected!

```
> insertionSort.getRecord(123);
[123, [1231, 1232, 1233, 1234, 1235]]
```

---

## And The Explanation

- The Bad Array Jump Destination `PC 00000651: JUMPI GAS: 1946706 COST: 10 ERROR: invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2` was probably due to the algorithm being incorrect and addressing the wrong index in the array. I just looked up the insertion sort algorithm and rewrote the code based on the algorithm I found.
- The main issue I had was that I originally had the `insertionSort()` function coded as follows:

  ```
  function insertionSort(uint[] a, uint length) internal {
    for (uint i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      uint j = i;
      while (j > 0 && a[j] < a[j-1]) {
        uint temp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[j-1];
        a[j-1] = temp;
        j--;
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  And I called it from `addRecordWithInsertionSort()` as:

  ```
  function addRecordWithInsertionSort(uint _recId, uint _num) public {
      Record record = records[_recId];
      record.recId = _recId;
      record.data.length++;
      record.data[record.data.length-1] = _num;
      insertionSort(record.data, record.data.length);
  }
  ```

  The data was not being sorted and this is most likely because the `record.data` variable was being passed to `insertionSort()` as a memory variable. The array was being sorted in the `insertionSort()` function, but the modified array was not being passed back to the calling function.

  According to [Solidity - Frequently Asked Questions](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html):

  > There are defaults for the storage location depending on which type of variable it concerns:
  >
  > ...
  >
  > ```
  >  * function arguments are always in memory.
  > ```

  I had to change the code such that the `insertionSort()` function returns the modified array.

  The new `insertionSort()` function is:

  ```
  function insertionSort(uint[] a, uint length) internal returns (uint[]) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      uint j = i;
      while (j > 0 && a[j] < a[j-1]) {
        uint temp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[j-1];
        a[j-1] = temp;
        j--;
      }
    }
    return a;
  }
  ```

  And the code calling `insertionSort()` modified to update the data from the return value of the `insertionSort()` function, and the results are now correct:

  ```
  function addRecordWithInsertionSort(uint _recId, uint _num) public { 
    Record record = records[_recId];
    record.recId = _recId;
    record.data.length++;
    record.data[record.data.length-1] = _num;
    record.data = insertionSort(record.data, record.data.length);
  }
  ```
- And last, I used **mapping** instead of **arrays** so I don't have to keep track of array indices.

---

## EDIT: Testing Out The Function Parameter With Storage

I got the above test code working by returning the sorted data as a function result and reassigning this data to the map.

The following code shows that you can also use the **storage** modifier with the parameter to the called function that will allow the function to sort the data passed to it with the changes persisted in the map data structure.

```
    function insertionSortStorage(uint[] storage a) internal {
      for (uint i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        uint j = i;
        while (j > 0 && a[j] < a[j-1]) {
          uint temp = a[j];
          a[j] = a[j-1];
          a[j-1] = temp;
          j--;
        }
      }
    }

    function addRecordWithInsertionSortStorage(uint _recId, uint _num) public {
        Record record = records[_recId];
        record.recId = _recId;
        record.data.length++;
        record.data[record.data.length-1] = _num;
        insertionSortStorage(record.data);
    }
```

With the test results showing a success:

```
insertionSort.addRecordWithoutInsertionSort(123, 1235, eth.accounts[0], {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: insertionSortCompiled.InsertionSort.code,
  gas: 1000000
});
insertionSort.addRecordWithoutInsertionSort(123, 1231, eth.accounts[0], {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: insertionSortCompiled.InsertionSort.code, 
  gas: 1000000
});
insertionSort.addRecordWithoutInsertionSort(123, 1232, eth.accounts[0], {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: insertionSortCompiled.InsertionSort.code,
  gas: 1000000
});
> insertionSort.getRecord(123);
[123, [1235, 1231, 1232]]

insertionSort.addRecordWithInsertionSortStorage(123, 1220, eth.accounts[0], {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: insertionSortCompiled.InsertionSort.code,
  gas: 2000000
});
> insertionSort.getRecord(123);
[123, [1220, 1231, 1232, 1235]]
```

---

## Replicating ERROR: invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2

I can replicate the `invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2` error by add the following function to the class:

```
function testInvalidJumpLocation() public constant returns (uint[5]) {
  uint[5] memory data;
  uint j = 1;
  j = j - 2;
  data[j] = 1235;
  return data;
}
```

And executing the function to get the following results:

```
insertionSort.testInvalidJumpLocation()
...
PC 00000304: JUMP GAS: 49978004 COST: 8 ERROR: invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2
...
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This error could have been caused by some other parts of your code, but an invalid array index definitely generates this message.