# Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination]

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, arrays, mapping

When calling to `start()` function in a Smart Contract, transaction fails with this message:

> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination]

According to [Error During Token Contract Execution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2932/error-during-token-contract-execution) ... an invalid array index definitely generates this message. So I have been thinking about it, trying to figure out when my code is using an invalid index, but I can't find it.

This is the method requested:

```
function start(address seller, address thirdParty) returns (uint escrowId) {
    escrowId = numEscrows;
    numEscrows++;
    escrow e;
    e.thirdParty = thirdParty;
    e.seller = seller;
    e.buyer = msg.sender;
    e.amount = msg.value;
    e.recipient = seller;
    e.status = 1; // started

    escrows[escrowId] = e;

    return escrowId;
}
```

The only array there is `escrows[]` declared as `mapping (uint => escrow) escrows;`

After trying different things, I came to conclusion that problem surely is located at last line: `escrows[escrowId] = e;`

Is not possible to make such an assignment `escrows[0] = e;`? Why not?

What am I doing wrong? How can I debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start(...)` and `start1(...)` are two ways you can rewrite your function to work as expected:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Ballot {
    struct Escrow {
        address thirdParty;
        address seller;
        address buyer;
        uint amount;
        address recipient;
        uint status;
    }
    uint numEscrows;
    mapping (uint => Escrow) escrows;

    function start(address seller, address thirdParty) returns (uint escrowId) {
        escrowId = numEscrows;
        numEscrows++;
        Escrow memory e;
        e.thirdParty = thirdParty;
        e.seller = seller;
        e.buyer = msg.sender;
        e.amount = msg.value;
        e.recipient = seller;
        e.status = 1; // started

        escrows[escrowId] = e;

        return escrowId;
    }

    function start1(address seller, address thirdParty) returns (uint escrowId) {
        escrows[numEscrows].thirdParty = thirdParty;
        escrows[numEscrows].seller = seller;
        escrows[numEscrows].buyer = msg.sender;
        escrows[numEscrows].amount = msg.value;
        escrows[numEscrows].recipient = seller;
        escrows[numEscrows].status = 1; // started
        numEscrows++;
        return numEscrows;
    }
}
```

And here is the Solidity realtime compiler and runtime screen showing that both `start(...)` and `start1(...)` execute without throwing an exception:

[image]

Note that `start1(...)` costs less gas than `start(...)`.

In `start(...)`, I added the **memory** keyword - see [What is the memory keyword? What does it do?](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-is-the-memory-keyword-what-does-it-do), [Difference between Memory and Storage?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/difference-between-memory-and-storage) and [What does the keyword "memory" do exactly?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/what-does-the-keyword-memory-do-exactly) for further information.

In your question, you mentioned "The only array there is escrows[] declared as `mapping (uint => escrow) escrows`;". Note that arrays are different from mappings - see [Arrays](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#arrays) vs [Mappings](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#mappings) and [Store data in mapping vs. array](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2592/store-data-in-mapping-vs-array).

Comment: The flag memory seems to have solved all my problems. Thx!